# UWP ExtendedExecution - Error when requesting Extended Execution

Tags: uwp, windows-10, xamarin.uwp

I have a UWP application that requests Extended Execution in a callback that gets fired after an operation starts like below:

```
private async void HandleOnSyncStart(ISyncStart msg)
{
    // request extended execution
    ExtendedExecutionResult result = await 
      Utils.ExtendedExecutionHelper.RequestExtendedExecutionSessionAsync();
}
```

, but I get following error

```
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the 
 requested operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007139F)
```

The error is thrown on return call in **RequestExtendedExecutionSessionAsync()** method shown below.  This is the stacktrace:

```
   at Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution.ExtendedExecutionSession..ctor()
   at MyProject.UWP.Utils.ExtendedExecutionHelper.<RequestExtendedExecutionSessionAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyProject.UWP.MainPage.<HandleOnSyncStart>d__65.MoveNext()
```

The extended execution session is requested in RequestExtendedExecutionAsync() method of ExtendedExecutionHelper static class like below:

```
    public static async Task<ExtendedExecutionResult> RequestExtendedExecutionSessionAsync()
    {
        ClearExtendedExecutionSession();  //first clear if any session granted

        var newSession = new ExtendedExecutionSession();
        newSession.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified;
        newSession.Description = "Extended Execution Request";
        newSession.Revoked += OnExtendedExecutionSessionRevoked;

        ExtendedExecutionResult result = await newSession.RequestExtensionAsync();
        switch (result)
        {
            case ExtendedExecutionResult.Allowed:
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ExtendedExecutionHelper: ExtendedExecution allowed."));
                session = newSession;
                break;
            case ExtendedExecutionResult.Denied:
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ExtendedExecutionHelper: ExtendedExecution denied."));
                newSession.Dispose();
                break;
        }

        return result; //ERROR
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is thrown in the constructor of `ExtendedExecutionSession` class.

> Stacktrace:
>   at Windows.ApplicationModel.ExtendedExecution.ExtendedExecutionSession..ctor()

And this exception can be caused by

> Only one ExtendedExecutionSession can be requested at any time; attempting to create another session while one is currently active will cause an exception to be thrown from the ExtendedExecutionSession constructor.

So it looks like `ClearExtendedExecutionSession` fails to dispose of a previous running session. If your code is adopted from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution)... maybe the code has some subtle bugs, as indicated in some comments on that page.

You could show how you deal with the previous running session.

Comment: I'm aware of the errors in that page, I fixed them.  But I don't get error when instantiating the session, see the line of code that errors.  I don't think it has to do anything with multiple EES as I'm not getting the error from EES ctor call.  Thanks

Comment: Actually, you are right, I tried calling EES c-tor twice one after another and that is exactly what I got.  Thanks,